# How to use an apiResource route parameter with where clause in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I want to pass a parameter to an apiResource route, and restrict permitted values with where clause, but laravel throw an error

```
Route::apiResource('/admin/{category}/attributes', 'AttributeController')
   ->where('category', 'industries|professions|studies|experiences|locations');
```

I got this error:

```
> BadMethodCallException Method
> Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::where does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass `options` as the third argument to the `Route::apiResource` method like this:

```php
Route::apiResource('/admin/{category}/attributes', 'AttributeController', [
    'where' => ['category' => 'industries|professions|studies|experiences|locations']
]);
```

Comment: i made a mistake in parameter name, it is category, not attribute